# array_filter multidimensial array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In my Laravel site I have this array:

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "asdf"
    "desc" => ""
    "date" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => ""
    "desc" => ""
    "date" => ""
  ]
]
```

I want to filter out the empty arrays in my array.
Simply doing

`$array = array_filter(request()->exp);`

does  nothing...

People suggested:

```
$array = array_filter(array_map('array_filter', request()->exp));
```

but this results in:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "asdf"
  ]
]
```

I need those other values even if theyre empty, or my next page wont work.

How do I get around this?

Eventually this has to come out:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "asdf"
    "desc" => ""
    "date" => ""
  ]
```

it just simply has to remove empty arrays in the one top array.

Comment: If you want to keep the empty values then don't filter your array?!

Comment: yes but i dont want the empty arrays

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question, this may help:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    $val1 = array_filter($val);
    if(!empty($val1)){
        $newArr[$key] = $val; // or $newArr[] = $val; if don't want to keep index
    }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: this returned: 


`array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "sadf"
    "desc" => ""
    "date" => ""
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => ""
    "desc" => ""
    "date" => ""
  ]
]` 


so basically it did nothing

Comment: update the answer, use `array_filter()` before `if` condition

Comment: this also results in 

`array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "title" => "asdfg"
  ]
]`

Comment: sorry, update the answer, hope this time it will work.

Comment: YES, that's exactly what I needed, than you so much!

Comment: Glad to help you, happy coding :)